# Replacing chained ifs with short-circuited operations

Tags: c++, c, short-circuiting

This is a very trivial problem:
There are four boolean functions: a(), b(), c() and d(). I want to keep calling them in order until the first one returns `true`. instead of doing the traditional

```
if(!a()) {
    if(!b()) {
        if(!c()) {
            d();
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
if(!a() && !b() && !c()) d();
```

I thought about writing the expression as a short-circuited evaluation.

```
(a() || b() || c() || d());
```

But I've never seen this test being done this way in a C/C++ code. Is there any problem with this approach that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: I can see *five* boolean functions.

Comment: @chris the or doesn't change the meaning: d() is executed only if all the other functions are false.

Comment: I'd advice against this from a maintenance perspective. It might not be immediately obvious to people what the code does when they see the short-circuited version (if that's a concern for you). The fact that you had to ask about the behavior at SO should be a hint at what will happen when other people read your code.

Comment: @Loghorn, Oops, you're right. My mistake. I just realized what the question is *really* asking.

Comment: It works. But like most tricky code, it is irresponsible to do something clever like this without explaining it, preferably in a comment immediately prior. Making it work is not as important as making sure that the next programmer to read it understands *why* it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written is valid. `d()` will only be evaluated if other boolean functions return `false`.

However the short-circuited evaluation is less readable, and error prone from a maintenance point of view, because a reader might not get understand it trivially.

Comment: You got it wrong.  `d()` is evaluated if NO OTHER function returned true.  Which I guess makes your point about readability.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Was in a hurry.

Comment: @user666412, not error-prone literally, but kinda hard to read and understand easily. See for instance, even I did the mistake while trying to answer the question when I was in a hurry, as pointed out by Ben Voigt, in the comments.

Comment: I thought it was a good answer +1. Error prone is fine, people understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent, but the short-circuited evaluation solution could be less readable, especially if function names are long or accepts parameters.